Expo debugging with last SDK
I'm working on a project based on Expo and recently I have to switch to a newer version (SDK 52.0.11) as expo go app was updated on my phone.
My code is working correctly but now when I want to debug my source and use the dev tool, I'm not always have the source loaded and even if I have the source execution is not breaking on any of my break point.
I search a lot of post and issue posted on github repo but currently I'm not finding any clue to have debugger working correctly.
Does anyone encounter same issue and have a workarround ?
thanks
